# Retrieving Element Names From The Class Map

Tags: c#, mongodb

Here's the class I am mapping to MongoDB:

```
public class Thing
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Saving it to the collection is great:

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<Thing>("things");
collection.Save(new Thing() {Foo = "one", Bar = "two"});
```

But when I want to search for it, I have to explicitly specify element names as strings:

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<Thing>("things");
collection.Find(Query.EQ("Foo", "one"));
```

There is no way for the compiler to help with these queries. I have to reference my class file, copy the element name, and paste it into the query. If I change the element name later, the compiler won't make sure that I changed it in the queries, let alone change it for me. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no support from a compiler perspective for querying in v1.3.1 of the official driver. We are currently working on LINQ support which should help with the mapping to element names.(https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-91). If you would like to see this outside LINQ please file an enhancement request at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP

Answer (score 1):

If you'll save your class map in a private member like so:

```
private static BsonClassMap<Thing> _thingClassMap = BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Thing>();
```

...

you could extract the element name:

```
string elementName = _thingClassMap.GetMemberMap<string>(c => c.Foo).ElementName;
```

...

and then you could just create a function that wraps the line that extracts the element name,
its still pretty annoying, but that's the best we got at the moment I guess..

```
 private string GetTypeMemberName<T>(Expression<Func<Foo, T>> memberLambda)
 {
        return _classMap.GetMemberMap<T>(memberLambda).ElementName;
 }
```

then you could simply get the element name by:

```
string elementName = GetTypeMemberName<string>(c => c.Foo);
```

Then if you refactor your code and rename the property later, it will also change in the query.

Of course, you can also just use LINQ.